# How do i write these type of loops in one line using python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, text-processing

I'm  novice at python. I'm trying to clean a text file for my NLP project. How can I write these few lines of code into a single line in python. I'm using NLTK for processing my text data.

```
sentences = [sent_tokenize(token) for token in doc]
words = [word_tokenize(''.join(sentence)) for sentence in sentences]
clean_words=[]
for word in words :
      for token in word :
           if token.isalnum() and token.lower() not in  list(stop_words):
                clean_words.append(token.lower())`
```

Comment: Why would you want to? It would be one messy line if it was even possible

Comment: @OferSadan I'm just curious to know if it can  be done? If so.. how would it be like.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are referring to nested list comprehensions? something like this :

```
clean_words = [t.lower() for w in words for t in w if t.isalnum() and t.lower() not in list(stop_words)]
```